# Recursive interface type parameter in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I am trying to understand this recursive `interface` definition in `apache thrift` source code

```
 public interface TBase<T extends TBase<?, ?>, F extends TFieldIdEnum> extends Comparable<T>, Serializable {
```

From my understanding `TBase` is a interface containing type parameter `T` and `F`.

`T` has the constraint that it also have to be extending `TBase` that has type parameter containing any type.

What I am confused about is what is the terminating `TBase`

Say I have

```
public class TBaseImpl<A, B> implements TBase<A, B>
```

`A` has to be a `TBase`

so there must be another class implement `A`

```
public class TBaseImplA<C, D> implements TBase<C, D>
```

but `C` have to be a `TBase`

so there must be another class implement `C`

This goes on forever.

So my question is

1. What is terminating condition for `TBase`
2. What is the benefit of this recursive definition?

Can someone point me a direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> so there must be another class implement A

That is not necessarily true.  With this type of recursive bounds, there are 2 possible ways to satisfy the constraint when creating a subtype.

1. Declare your own type parameter with the same or more restrictive bounds.  This places the burden of choosing the type parameter on the user of this class.

```
public class TBaseImpl<A extends TBase<A, B>, B extends TFieldIdEnum> implements TBase<A, B>
```

or more likely

```
public class TBaseImpl<A extends TBaseImpl<A, B>, B extends TFieldIdEnum> implements TBase<A, B>
```

2. Pass the same class as what you're defining to satisfy the original bound.

```
public class TBaseImpl<B extends TFieldIdEnum> implements TBase<TBaseImpl, B>
```

A benefit of this pattern is being able to restrict the parameter of a method that is meant to take in another instance of the same class, e.g.:

```
public void example(T other)
```

This is (in Java) the [Curiously Repeating Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Normally an implementing/overriding method must match the parameter types and order of parameters exactly.  But this pattern allows you to narrow the type by narrowing the type parameter.  E.g. such a method in `TBaseImpl` in this case would only take a `TBaseImpl` and not the broader `T` or `TBase`.  In such a class there is a relationship between the class and itself.

Another benefit is method chaining, in which a method returns `this` to allow

```
obj.method1().method2().method3()
```

In this way, chaining methods can be declared to return `T`, so that e.g. a `TBase<TBaseImpl>` variable can call these methods, each returning a `TBaseImpl` on which another method can be called.

```
T method1();  // in TBase

@Override
TBaseImpl method1(); // in TBaseImpl
```

Incidentally, if you're trying to declare a type variable that is a subtype of an enum, that's not necessary because an `enum` is `final` and cannot be extended.  It would be simpler to remove `F` in the interface and have implementing classes use the enum directly.

Comment: "A benefit of this pattern is being able to restrict the parameter of a method that is meant to take in another instance of the same class, e.g.: public void example(T other)" But it *doesn't* restrict `T` to be an instance of the same class